# People Reached tooltip is cut on some sites when viewing own profile

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, people-reached

When I moved my mouse cursor over Impact (Approximate no. of people reached) in my [Pro Webmasters Profile Page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/current), few of the contents are not visible. They are going behind the header banner. But I checked 
some SE sites and they are looking fine. I checked through Firefox 40.0.3. Does it is a bug? Do SE site is not compatible with latest Firefox version?

*Screenshot:*

**Pro Webmasters:**

> [image]

**Meta SE:**

> [image]

This other bug report on User Experience site proves it's not specific only to one site: ["People reached" tooltip covered by navigation header](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1966/people-reached-tooltip-covered-by-navigation-header)

Comment: CSS bug, and not only in Firefox. (happens for me with Chrome too, probably in all browsers)

Comment: @rene maybe it was specific to one site only and got migrated.

Comment: @rene found one, though it wasn't migrated. Anyway, this proves it's not site specific and belongs here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So shall I remove the text `But not in other SE` from the title of this question as it is also in UX?

Comment: Yeah, I did it myself, also improving title a bit.

Comment: Also happens at [webapps.se]: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/tooltip-flows-under-header

Comment: Seems to be on sites where there is a horizontal coloured band at the top, ie ProWebmasters has a light blue band, WebApplications is grey, etc. (Although I cannot find the CSS so maybe it's something back end which produces the site specific branding)