# Increase width of tooltip blocks in the profile page

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, tooltips

Width of the tooltip for impact block in the user profile page is too small (looks ugly for me):

> [image: impact]

Small width looks good for short text (2-3 lines):

> [image: rep]
>
> [image: badge]

But not for a long text as in the impact block.

Is it possible to increase width so as to split resulting text into 2-3 lines according text length? This also could be good for localized sites.

Comment: Related bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266675/people-reached-tooltip-is-cut-on-some-sites-when-viewing-own-profile (that's not ordinary HTML tooltip but rather custom JS tooltip)

Comment: Easy fix... [replace `max-width` with `width`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAytP.png)